# How to combine Django TestCase test wit PyTest test in one tests.py file?

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest

I have code in tests.py (Django tests):

```
class MyTest1(TestCase):
   ...

class MyTest2(TestCase):
   ...

class MyTest3(TestCase):
   ...
```

as well as few pytest tests (in regular functions with proper pytest decorators), but Django after using command:

**python manage.py test**

is not taking into account pytest tests. This tests are not used.

What should I change in my tests.py file? How to deal with two types of tests?

Comment: I don't know if they can be combined, but, in case you did not know, [this library](https://github.com/dusty-phillips/django-pytest) might help you get there.

Comment: Yes, they can be in one file, but then we need to test using pytest command, as django is checking only its own tests.